# Not able to bind user input to java parameters in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Error:

**[nio-8083-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8083-exec-1] Exception processing template "index": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 72, col 82)**

I am not able to bind input form to parameters variables.

Here is the Thymeleaf template which is index.html

```
<!--/*@thymesVar id="parameters" type="com.sabre.dashboard.parameters.Parameters"*/-->
<form action="reports.html" th:action="@{/reports.html}" th:object="${parameters}" method="post">
        <p>
            ReleaseId: <label for="releaseId"></label><input type="text" th:field="*{releaseId}" id="releaseId" name="releaseId">
        </p>
        <p>
            Date: <label for="releaseId"></label><input type="date" th:field="*{date}" id="date" name="date">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
   </form>
```

Here is the controller class

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/reports",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String setReleaseId()
{

    return "index";
}
```

Here is the parameter class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.Date;

public class Parameters {


private String releaseId;
private Date date;

public Parameters() {
    super();
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}


public String getReleaseId() {
    return releaseId;
}

public void setReleaseId(String releaseId) {
    this.releaseId = releaseId;
}

}
```

I have other controller class which fetch the data from parameters class. But not able to bind user inuput releaseid and date to parameters class variables. How to approach this?